# Inject object d3.js drag and drop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I do drag and drop in d3.js:

```
var drag=d3.behavior.drag()
          .on('dragstart', function(cs) { c.style('fill', 'red'); })
          .on('drag', function() { c.attr('cx', d3.event.x) .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
        })
    c.call(drag);
```

I have object:

```
var coords={
   x:0,
   y:0
    };
```

how to update the **coords**(x and y) while dragging?

Answer (score 0):

when drag event is applied just assign the d3.event coordinates to your object like this:

```
  var drag=d3.behavior.drag()
      .on('dragstart', function(cs) { c.style('fill', 'red'); })
      .on('drag', function() {
              c.attr('cx', d3.event.x).attr('cy',d3.event.y);
              coords.x= d3.event.x;
              coords.y= d3.event.y;
    })
c.call(drag);
```